# Connect Points using line different table in QGIS3

Tags: qgis, points-to-line

I have two tables.

Table1 is having many point objects (Sample given below)
Table2 shows the connectivity between the point object(using a link) and link details

My requirement is to have a new Line layer connecting point objects from Table1 as per the Link in Table2.

example : I need to have one line connecting A1 to A3 with a name of "A1_A3", another Line connecting A5 to A4 name of the line to be A5_A4)

I tried with few plugins like connectpoints & points2one... But no luck.

[image: Points]

[image: Links]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In QGIS, you can create a Virtual layer (Edit Menu > Create Layer > New Virtual Layer) with the code below :

```sql
SELECT t3."SI No",
       t3."Link ID",
       t3."Link Desc",
       make_line(ST_GeomFromText(t3.ptfrom), ST_GeomFromText(t3.ptto)) AS geom
FROM (SELECT "Table2"."SI No",
             "Table2"."Link ID",
             "Table2"."Link Desc",
              ST_AsText(t1from.geometry) AS ptfrom,
              ST_AsText(t1to.geometry) AS ptto
      FROM "Table2"
      INNER JOIN "Table1" t1from ON "Table2"."From" = t1from."Object name"
      INNER JOIN "Table1" t1to ON "Table2"."To" = t1to."Object name") AS t3
```

Usually, the SQL query is more simple but here, I've tried to reproduce your case with two memory layers (Table1 point, Table2 no geometry) and I had to transform point geometry into text (WKT) to have both Table1 fields.